# Remove parameters from redirect

Tags: .htaccess

I have set up a redirect in an .htaccess file where I'm trying to remove the parameter from being added to the redirect rule. The rule I have set up is:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ^windward\.net$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^cat=1$
RewriteRule ^2013/$ https://www.windwardstudios.com/? [R=301,L]
```

I'm trying to redirect from 2013/?cat=1$ to https://www.windwardstudios.com/ but the redirect URL is:

https://www.windwardstudios.com/?cat=1

How do I remove the ?cat=1 from the redirected URL?

Comment: Your rule looks ok . Maybe try clearing your browser cache.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)&?cat=[^&]+&?(.*)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /$1?%1%2 [R=301,L]
```